# itorch do not display any image

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, torch

I am doing iTorch but stucked

I followed this installation step in https://github.com/facebook/iTorch(for itorch)

I did just like github/facebook/iTorch said

in itorch console mode, entered this code

```
in[1] itorch.image({image.lena(),image.lena(),image.lena()})
in[2] itorch.audio('volkswagen.mp3')
in[3] itorch.video('samll.mp4')
in[4] and plotting
```

But nothing happen
just shows blank

```
out[1]:


in[2]:
```

And during plotting, I entered plot:save('out.html') then it makes out.html and that file shows correct image.

version list is :
Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
ipython version 4.0.0
Python 2.7.3
torch works well

plz tell me how to solve it!!

Comment: try in the notebook mode `itorch notebook`

Comment: thank u!! it works on itorch notebook